# When to check if item already exists in C++ set/map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, set, unordered-map, unordered-set

I have a general question regarding set, unordered_set, map, unordered_map in C++ STL.

I often see code that checks if an item is already in a set/map before attempting to alter its value.

I was wondering, when is it advisable to manually check if an item already exists in the set/map before attempting to modify it?

For example:

```
unordered_set<string> banwords(banned.begin(), banned.end());
unordered_map<string, int> count;
string word = "test";

if (banwords.find(word) == banwords.end()){

    ++count[word];
    if (count[word] > maxpair.second){
        maxpair.first = word;
        maxpair.second = count[word];
    }
}
```

No checking is done to determine whether word already exists in count, instead it is assumed that `count[word] = 0` before it even exists in the map.

On the other hand, I've seen other threads that encourage checking if the item exists first.

What is recommended solution here?

Answer (score 4):

The key here is that when `word` is not already in the map, `count[word]` creates a new entry in the map, with a key of `word` and a value of 0. So `++count[word]` is always valid; no need to check.

Answer (score 0):

Since the objective of the code you show is to get the non-banned word that occurs most often, you need to check to see if the word is in the banned list first.  Then you can just directly access `count[word]` (without checking) because, if `word` is not in `count`, it will be inserted with the default value stored as the value (`int()`, which will be 0).

There is no the general rule for if you should check to see if a key exists in a map or set.  That depends on how you're using it and what your objectives are.

Incidentally, in the code you've shown, since are two (or three) calls to `count[word]`, there will be two (or three) lookups in the map to locate the key/value pair.  Using `int c = ++count[word];`, then referencing `c` in the other two places can give a small performance improvement.